# how to post recaptcha responsive by jquery to a action in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, recaptcha

I have created an action to post user's comment with jQuery in ASP.NET MVC using C#. This is my `AddComment` action that get model as a parameter.

This action method returns a partial view and doesn't return a view:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult AddComment(PageComment form)
    {
        try
        {
            if ( ModelState.IsValid )
            {
                PageComment addComment = new PageComment()
                {
                    CreateDate = DateTime.Now,
                    PageId = form.PageId,
                    Comment = form.Comment,
                    Email = form.Email,
                    Name = form.Name
                };
                pageCommentRepository.addPageComment(addComment);

                return PartialView("ShowComment", pageCommentRepository.GetCommentByNewsID(addComment.PageId));
            }
            else
            {
                return PartialView("ShowComment", pageCommentRepository.GetCommentByNewsID(form.PageId));
            }
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError);
        }
    }
```

My problem is that how I can get "Recaptcha Response" with other member of my model.

This is my jQuery function:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
     function addComment(parameters) {
        var form = {
            PageId: $("#Id").val(),
            Name: $("#Name").val(),
            Email: $("#Email").val(),
            Comment: $("#Comment").val()
        };
        $.ajax({
            type: "Post",
            url: "@Url.Action("AddComment", "News" , new {@id = @Model.PageId})",
            data: form
        }).done(function (result) {
            $("#commentList").html(result);
            $("#Name").val("");
            $("#Email").val("");
            $("#Comment").val("");
        });
    }
</script>
```

Actually I want to use google recaptcha v2.This is my form section of view page.

```html
<form class="comment-form" action="" method="post" id="commentForm">
    <div>
        <input type="hidden" id="Id" value="@Model.PageId" />
        <input placeholder="Please enter your family and name" type="text" id="Name">
        <input placeholder="Please enter your mail address" type="email" id="Email">
        
        <br />
    </div>
  
    <textarea placeholder="Comment text" id="Comment"> </textarea>
    <input value="Submit your Comment" type="button" onclick="addComment()" id="register-button">
</form>
```

I tried to get "recaptcha response" from page payload with request.form[""] command, but it returns null!